# Friendly rivallary with MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow, cross-posting

Does it exist? I was going to post a question on MathOverflow, but I felt incredibly guilty all of a sudden. Is cross-posting allowed?

Comment: Crossposting is discouraged.  MO is for posts by research mathematicians about research-level mathematics. Unless you are a professional research mathematician, it is unlikely that your post will be on-topic for MO.

Comment: don 't you want to know what my question is?

Comment: No, I trust you to make the correct choice now that I have explained the criteria.

Comment: Also, to answer your question, I have not observed any rivalry between the two sites, which serve different purposes and largely (but not entirely) disjoint audiences.

Comment: Yes, not sure about the "friendly" bit though. ;-)

Comment: this ones quite interesting - i think he is asking how many new AP's are formed when the n-th prime is added to the set.:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104059/the-topology-of-arithmetic-progressions-of-primes

Comment: okay, ill tell you my question...

Comment: does x.x=x.x in a non-abelian field?

Comment: Did you mistype the question? The left and right are litterally the same, how could the be not equal?

Comment: i was asking for a simple proof, the technical words might be rusty aswell

Comment: But RH and LH are *the very  same string.*

Comment: but the field is non-abelian

Comment: @Asaf I am not sure "cross posting" is meant in that sense.

Comment: I wanted to vote as a duplicate of: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo but the silly closure dialog decided to take a different question as what I'd meant (admittedly, my fault). So I'm only linking this.

Comment: "but the field is non-abelian" so what? $xy$ will still equal $xy$ and even more so $xx$ will equal $xx$. How in the world should $xx$ be something other than $xx$?

Comment: what if i had said non-commutative?

Comment: This would be the same. And it is also irrlelevant. You will have a hard time to find whatever context where an expression is not considered equal to itself.

Comment: in Javascript x=y <> x==y <> x===y but x==y is the same as y==x, but not x=y as y=x.

Comment: Which expression is not considered as equal to itself in the example you give? Moreover = there denotes an assignment, at least I guess so, and not a test for equality it is thus quite irrelevant.

Comment: true - i'm giving up on this one, i guess xx=xx after all, regardless of field

Comment: @quid; have you got any idea what this one means: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95711/approximately-bijective-proof-of-zeta2-pi2-6

Comment: Yes, more or less.

Comment: what is ||A|| ? sqrt(x^2+y^2)?

Comment: Yes, this, the usual norm.